# I can't access my variables from another class

Tags: java

I am working on a simple Bingo game that has randomized numbers. My main class (Bingo) is here:(note that I have more code that is not relevant to the problem)`

```
public class Bingo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        RandNum columnB = new RandNum();
        columnB.max = 15;
        columnB.randNum();
        int b1 = columnB.row1;
        int b2 = columnB.row2;
        int b3 = columnB.row3;
        int b4 = columnB.row4;
        int b5 = columnB.row5;

        RandNum columnI = new RandNum();
        columnI.min = 16;
        columnI.max = 30;
        columnI.randNum();
        int i1 = columnI.row1;
        int i2 = columnI.row2;
        int i3 = columnI.row3;
        int i4 = columnI.row4;
        int i5 = columnI.row5;

        RandNum columnN = new RandNum();
        columnN.min = 31;
        columnN.max = 45;
        columnN.randNum();
        int n1 = columnN.row1;
        int n2 = columnN.row2;
        int n3 = columnN.row3;
        int n4 = columnN.row4;
        int n5 = columnN.row5;

        RandNum columnG = new RandNum();
        columnG.min = 46;
        columnG.max = 60;
        columnG.randNum();
        int g1 = columnG.row1;
        int g2 = columnG.row2;
        int g3 = columnG.row3;
        int g4 = columnG.row4;
        int g5 = columnG.row5;

        RandNum columnO = new RandNum();
        columnO.min = 61;
        columnO.max = 75;
        columnO.randNum();
        int o1 = columnO.row1;
        int o2 = columnO.row2;
        int o3 = columnO.row3;
        int o4 = columnO.row4;
        int o5 = columnO.row5;
    }
}
```

My class that I am using to generate the random numbers:

```
public class RandNum {
    int min = 1;
    int max;

    public void randNum() {
        Random rn = new Random();

        int row1 = rn.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int row2 = rn.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int row3 = rn.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int row4 = rn.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
        int row5 = rn.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that I am trying to set my b1, b2, etc variables to the variable row1, etc. in the RandNum class. I know that I could just put it all in one class but this is a problem I have had multiple times so I'd like to solve it. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: please use a loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you are declaring `rowX` variables as local variables in your `randNum()` method.

This makes that its scope is only that method, so they won't exist / be available outside it.

**What can you do?**
Declare them as class attributes:

```
public class RandNum {
    int row1, row2, row3, row4, row5;
    ...
    public void randNum() {...}
}
```

**Note:** You could use an array instead:

```
int[] rows = new int[5];
```

Then in your method:

```
public void randNum() {
    Random rn = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); i++)
        rows[i] = rn.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `b` etc. variables are scoped to the `main` method of `Bingo` so you'll never be able to access them from another class - or another method of the same class for that matter.

You could set them as `public static` fields of `Bingo` instead of declaring them within the method's body (or `private`s with getters), but due to the number of variables you have here, I suggest refactoring first and investigating a few data structures such as `Collection`s and `Map`s.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it. The variables `b1`,`b2`,... are local to your `randNum` function and will be out of scope once execution exits the function. The solution is to store the variables in a field in the `RandNum` class.

```
public class RandNum{
    private int[] rows = new int[5];
    private int min;
    private int max;

    public RandNum(int min, int max) {
        Random rn = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
           rows[i] = rn.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    }

    public int getRow(int row) {
       return rows[i];
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    RandNum columnB = new RandNum(1,15);
    int b1 = columnB.getRow(0);
    int b2 = columnB.getRow(1);
    int b3 = columnB.getRow(2);
    int b4 = columnB.getRow(3);
    int b5 = columnB.getRow(4);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**See:** [***Why use getters and setters?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Create accessors/mutators:

```
public class RandNum {
    private int min;
    private int max;

    public RandNum(int min, int max) {
        setMin(min);
        setMax(max);
    }

    public RandNum() {
        this(1, 0);
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then use them:

```
public class Bingo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        RandNum columnB = new RandNum();
        columnB.setMax(15);
        // ...
    }
}
```